# ConfigurationSetupException: The configuration data in the base configuration from server does not obey the Terracotta schema (tc-config.xml)

Tags: java, ehcache, terracotta

I want to use terracotta (terracotta 4.3.3 + ehcache 2.6.8) in spring in order to implement caching some data. When I tried run, I got this error :

```js
03:10:10,320 ERROR [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in class path resource [foundationCommonContext-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcache' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcache' defined in class path resource [foundationCommonContext-service.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Unable to load class net.sf.ehcache.terracotta.StandaloneTerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory. Initial cause was java.lang.RuntimeException: com.tc.config.schema.setup.ConfigurationSetupException: 
*******************************************************************************
The configuration data in the base configuration from server at '127.0.0.1:9510' does not obey the Terracotta schema:
  [0]: Line 8, column 9: Expected element 'server' instead of 'mirror-group' here in element servers
  [1]: Line 31, column 9: Expected element 'server' instead of 'garbage-collection' here in element servers
  [2]: Line 36, column 9: Expected element 'server' instead of 'restartable' here in element servers
  [3]: Line 37, column 9: Expected element 'server' instead of 'client-reconnect-window' here in element servers

*******************************************************************************

 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:798) [jetty-server-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444) [jetty-servlet-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:789) [jetty-server-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294) [jetty-servlet-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341) [jetty-webapp-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:296) [jetty-maven-plugin-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334) [jetty-webapp-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741) [jetty-server-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497) [jetty-webapp-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:365) [jetty-maven-plugin-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) [jetty-util-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) [jetty-util-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) [jetty-server-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:163) [jetty-server-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) [jetty-util-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) [jetty-util-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) [jetty-server-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) [jetty-util-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387) [jetty-server-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) [jetty-util-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) [jetty-server-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354) [jetty-server-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:73) [jetty-maven-plugin-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:534) [jetty-maven-plugin-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:357) [jetty-maven-plugin-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:167) [jetty-maven-plugin-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132) [maven-core-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208) [maven-core-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153) [maven-core-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145) [maven-core-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116) [maven-core-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80) [maven-core-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51) [maven-core-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120) [maven-core-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347) [maven-core-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154) [maven-core-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582) [maven-embedder-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214) [maven-embedder-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158) [maven-embedder-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar:?]
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar:?]
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar:?]
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar:?]
```

when i run my terracotta server, i got no error :

```html
./start-tc-server.sh -f ../config/tc-config.xml 
2016-12-10 03:09:01,931 INFO - Terracotta 4.3.3, as of 20161014-074934 (Revision 27037 from 4.3.3)
2016-12-10 03:09:02,241 WARN - 
********************************* WARNING **********************************
* DataStorage offheap size not specified. Using a default of 2g
****************************************************************************

2016-12-10 03:09:02,255 INFO - Successfully loaded base configuration from file at '/home/asyst/Software/terracotta-4.3.3/server/bin/../config/tc-config.xml'.
2016-12-10 03:09:02,378 INFO - Log file: '/home/asyst/terracotta/server-logs/terracotta-server.log'.
2016-12-10 03:09:02,399 INFO - Available Max Runtime Memory: 1963MB
2016-12-10 03:09:08,231 INFO - Becoming State[ ACTIVE-COORDINATOR ]
2016-12-10 03:09:08,274 INFO - Terracotta Server instance has started up as ACTIVE node on 127.0.0.1:9510 successfully, and is now ready for work.
2016-12-10 03:09:09,922 INFO - Management server started on 0.0.0.0:9540
```

My tc-config.xml doesn't have any element mentioned on the error :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<tc:tc-config xmlns:tc="http://www.terracotta.org/config">
 <servers>
     <server host="127.0.0.1" name="My Server Name" bind="0.0.0.0">
        <data>/home/asyst/terracotta/server-data</data>
        <logs>/home/asyst/terracotta/server-logs</logs>
   <tsa-port bind="127.0.0.1">9510</tsa-port>
        <jmx-port bind="127.0.0.1">9520</jmx-port>
   <tsa-group-port bind="127.0.0.1">9530</tsa-group-port>
     </server>
 </servers>
  
   <clients>
     <logs>logs-%i</logs>
 </clients>

 <tc-properties>
     <property name="l2.nha.dirtydb.autoDelete" value="true"/>
     <property name="l1.cachemanager.enabled" value="true"/>
     <property name="logging.maxLogFileSize" value="1024"/>
   </tc-properties>
  
</tc:tc-config>
```

here my ehcache.xml :

```html
<ehcache updateCheck="false">

    <!-- Sets the path to the directory where cache .data files are created.

         If the path is a Java System Property it is replaced by
         its value in the running VM.

         The following properties are translated:
         user.home - User's home directory
         user.dir - User's current working directory
         java.io.tmpdir - Default temp file path -->
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
 

    <!--Default Cache configuration. These will applied to caches programmatically created through
        the CacheManager.

        The following attributes are required:

        maxElementsInMemory            - Sets the maximum number of objects that will be created in memory
        eternal                        - Sets whether elements are eternal. If eternal,  timeouts are ignored and the
                                         element is never expired.
        overflowToDisk                 - Sets whether elements can overflow to disk when the in-memory cache
                                         has reached the maxInMemory limit.

        The following attributes are optional:
        timeToIdleSeconds              - Sets the time to idle for an element before it expires.
                                         i.e. The maximum amount of time between accesses before an element expires
                                         Is only used if the element is not eternal.
                                         Optional attribute. A value of 0 means that an Element can idle for infinity.
                                         The default value is 0.
        timeToLiveSeconds              - Sets the time to live for an element before it expires.
                                         i.e. The maximum time between creation time and when an element expires.
                                         Is only used if the element is not eternal.
                                         Optional attribute. A value of 0 means that and Element can live for infinity.
                                         The default value is 0.
        diskPersistent                 - Whether the disk store persists between restarts of the Virtual Machine.
                                         The default value is false.
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds- The number of seconds between runs of the disk expiry thread. The default value
                                         is 120 seconds.
        -->
        
    <terracottaConfig url="127.0.0.1:9510"/>

    <defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        eternal="false"
        
        timeToIdleSeconds="120"
        timeToLiveSeconds="120">
        <terracotta />
    </defaultCache>
</ehcache>
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Terracotta 4.3.3 requires Ehcache 2.10.3.

The problem comes from the fact that you are trying to use Ehcache 2.6.8.

As of Terracotta 4.3 OSS servers, dot releases can differ but `major.minor` must be matching, which is `4.3.x` with `2.10.x` with a strong not in saying that differences should be limited to the duration of rolling upgrades, not as a general runtime configuration.